# How to remove last space from printf output

Tags: c, printf

I print out each element of the array through the gap

```
// n - array length
for(x=0; x<n; x++){
    printf("%d ", a[x]);
}
```

It returns me:

```
1 2 3 4 5 [space here]
```

How to remove latest space (character)?

Comment: (Don't add the space to begin with.)

Comment: "Removing" an already printed character is generally impossible -- you can attempt to overwrite it with a backspace but that relies on your console setup. The logical thing to do is Just Don't Print It.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(x=0; x<n; x++){
    if(x == n-1)
    printf("%d", a[x]); /* Print without space when printing last element */
    else
    printf("%d ", a[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, IMHO more readable approach:

```
for ( x = 0; x < n; x++ )
{
   if (x > 0)
     putchar(' ');
   printf("%d", a[x]);
}
```

Comment: this still prints the trailing space

Comment: @user3629249 (a) No: https://ideone.com/D0x9F5 (b) how could it? It never prints anything *after* any number, only *before* certain numbers;

Answer (score 2):

The way is simple:

```
for(x=0; x<n; x++){
    printf("%d", a[x]);
    if(x<(n-1)){
         printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(x=0; x<n-1; x++){
    printf("%d ", a[x]);
}
if(n > 0)
    printf("%d", a[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A "branch-less" variant of Paul Roub's solution. It requires that `n > 0` holds (i.e. consequently there exist at least one element in `a` array).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, n, a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    n = 5;

    printf("%d", a[0]);
    for (x = 1; x < n; x++)
        printf(" %d", a[x]);

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is posting their own answers, so here's my own.

```
int n, i;
for (i = 1, n = 5; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%d%s", i, i < n ? " " : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would recommend this method, but something like this will work too:

```
for ( x = 0; x < n; x++ )
{
    printf("%c%d", " "[!x], a[x]);
}
```

It's a bit cheaty, but neat in my opinion.